# How to split a string into individual letters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a string that represent a number like 1234567890 and I want to split this into individual digits, somehow as follows:

```
<div class="counter">
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
char[] num = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' }

string TotalCount = @Model.Count;
string[] TheDigit = TotalCount.Split(num);

foreach (var TheDigit in TotalCount)
{ 
<li>TheDigit</li>
}
}
</div>
```

How can I achieve this properly? Anyway my output must be something like this:

```
<li>1</li><li>2</li>...<li>9</li><li class="Zero">0</li>
```

Comment: `ToCharArray()` ? or more simply: `foreach(char c in  theString)  {...}` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Why not simply use the `[]` operator?

Comment: array of chars in `Split` method is a separators, not the desired output

Comment: @alessiobortolato the indexer? sure, kinda the same as the `foreach` though

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, when i added my comment there wasn't the foreach part in yours

Comment: @alessiobortolato I did a ninja edit ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is not view logic, IMHO, so it should not be done in the view but in the controller. Opinions may vary on this.

To the point, if you need to obtain the digits of a number, you can do it arithmetically or string-wise. String-wise you could do (assuming that normal digits occupy only a character, culture info, bla bla, turkish I, bla):

```
var x = "1234567";
foreach(var digit in x)
{
    <li>@digit</li>
}
```

Comment: I have to do this for styling purpose only. Anyway I am (very) new to MVC so this is the place that I find convenient to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `char[]` which contains digits and you want following as result?

```
<li>1</li><li>2</li>...<li>9</li>
```

You could use...

```
string result = string.Concat(num.Select(c => string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad: I forgot to convert to string. Anyway is working as follows:

```
<div>
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
<ul class="counter clearfix">
@{
string str = Model.Count.ToString();
foreach (var TheDigit in str)
{
<li>@TheDigit</li>
}
}
</ul>
}
<div>
<span>Joburi</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you guys